# Check if object is being drawn in the scene

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

We can have multiple objects in a 3D Blender model.
If we rotate the model, then it can be possible that certain object might 
not be visible at all from the user view as it is behind other objects.

How to check in Blender python whether an object is being rendered on scene at all or not?

Comment: What do you mean "visible", visible where, using what render engine, Viewport, Blender Internal, Cycles? An object may be "out of view" but still have an influence on the scene like casting shadows or emitting light, so not being directly visible in the view-cone may not mean it is totally invisible to the user. There may be more complexity to your question than you imagine, I think this is generally regarded a complex optimization done in game engines and real time rendering that is not trivial to accomplish.

Comment: I'm not talking about actual visibility settings. Of course visible objects will have impact on rendering. I want to know if at least a single pixel of an object is being drawn in viewport.

For example, if we are viewing a car from front, then it's tail light on the back are not drawn at all as they are completely obscured by other parts. But if we rotate the car model, then some part of it might be drawn on viewport depending on the amount of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know if this can be a solution for you or not, but here's what I would try:

Use either Object Index or Material Index to create a pass that will be like a mask of the object's outline.

So for example, in Cycles if you create a material with a Pass Index of 1 (as is on this cube)...

[image: Pass Index 1]

[image: Passes - Material Index enabled]

Then you could set up your nodes to get a mask from that like so:

[image: Material Index Pass]

Note that since the monkey object in front of the cube *does not* have a Material Index of 1, it occludes the cube.

You can set this up using the File Output node so that this gets output separately from the main render as its own file:

[image: File Output Node gives this as a separate file]

*Then* you can use an external script (in Python perhaps) to batch scan your frames and return TRUE when white pixels are found, or FALSE when the frame is all black.

This is a very specific use case, so expect to have to do custom scripting.